# Sort View in delegate

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to sort the view by adding view delegate like this:

```
public class AppointmentEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<AppointmentEntry>
  {
    protected virtual IEnumerable appointmentRecords()
    {
        PXView select = new PXView(Base, true, Base.AppointmentRecords.View.BqlSelect);
        int totalrow = 0;
        int startrow = PXView.StartRow;
        select.OrderByNew<OrderBy<Desc<FSAppointment.createdDateTime>>>();
        List<object> result = select.Select(PXView.Currents, PXView.Parameters, PXView.Searches, PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings, PXView.Filters, ref startrow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref totalrow);
        PXView.StartRow = 0;
        return result;
    }
}
```

It loads the latest record (by date), but when I navigate to next record it displays the same record. It only displays different one when I click on Last Record.

[image]

Comment: if the goal is to change the navigation, it might be best to update the question and title so other users can find the answer better.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the view you want in your extension if you use the same name (without needing to work with the view delegate). For example if the base graph view has something like this...

```
public PXSelect<SomeDac> AppointmentRecords;
```

In your extension graph you can do this for that view...

```
public PXSelect<SomeDac, OrderBy<SomeNewOrder>> AppointmentRecords;
```

**EDIT**: overriding the view delegate or using a view override will not change order by for the primary view. Leaving this answer in case anyone else is trying to do the same. Doing so might change the order for a view linked to a grid.

Comment: Hi!
I updated the graph with the code in you have provided me. But for some reason, there is no effect.

`public PXSelect<FSAppointment, Where<FSAppointment.srvOrdType, Equal<Optional<FSAppointment.refNbr>>>> AppointmentRecords;`

And the strange part is even though I remove the old code, effect of code is still there which means navigation is not working properly which used to work properly. And to confirm that I put the same code in new fresh instance. Is there anyway that the could would have had made affect is the data view permanently?

Comment: By the way, I had followed this blog: http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/06/using-pxview-in-dataview-delegate.html
which says it is better to use dataview delegate that to override dataview itself.

Comment: I assume you published after making your changes? are you on 6.1 or 2017R2? I don't have field service configured to try this. However I could test to confirm this works on navigation on another page such as sales order... I have dont this to change sort order in a grid in the past but that would not impact the navigation as it was not the primary view

Comment: yes that is true you loose out on changes made to the core view... which is why we no longer have that type of mod in place. So yes for the long term the dataview delegate would be preferred. I am trying this logic out on a screen i have handy... will update

Comment: it doesn't look like making the change to the overriding view like my answer states even works. You can override the buttons as I have done this to add navigation to a processing page. Is the goal for your requirement to simply change the navigation buttons?

Comment: I am using Acumatica 6.1. Before, I had problems on navigation only but later found out that delete isn't working as well. So, I think it overrides whole dataview and uses different cache. So, it would be great to have data view extension rather than override.

Comment: i was asking about the navigation buttons but looks like Ruslans answer beat me to it. If you are simply changing the buttons his answer will work. I have done this one other pages and works perfectly for navigation changes.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve the desired behavior is by replacement of the Appointments data entry page with a Generic Inquiry configured to sort records in any given order:
[image]
[image]

If replacing Appointments data entry page with a Generic Inquiry is not an option, you will have to override all 4 navigations buttons following the code snippet below (the Insert and Delete buttons should not have any issues as it was with the previous code sample). Also, keep in mind, the Appointment Nbr selector will still order FSAppointment records in descending order by the Appointment Nbr field. This is due to PXSelectorAttribute allowing to sort records only by its foreign key or substitute key, if one is defined.

```
using PX.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace FieldService.ServiceDispatch
{
    public class AppointmentEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<AppointmentEntry>
    {
        public PXFirstCst<FSAppointment> First;
        public PXPreviousCst<FSAppointment> Previous;
        public PXNextCst<FSAppointment> Next;
        public PXLastCst<FSAppointment> Last;

        public class PXFirstCst<TNode> : PXFirst<TNode>
            where TNode : class, IBqlTable, new()
        {
            public PXFirstCst(PXGraph graph, string name)
                : base(graph, name)
            {
            }
            public PXFirstCst(PXGraph graph, Delegate handler)
                : base(graph, handler)
            {
            }

            [PXUIField(DisplayName = ActionsMessages.First, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
            [PXFirstButton]
            protected override IEnumerable Handler(PXAdapter adapter)
            {
                adapter = PrepareCustomNavAdapter(this, adapter);
                return base.Handler(adapter);
            }
        }

        public class PXPreviousCst<TNode> : PXPrevious<TNode>
            where TNode : class, IBqlTable, new()
        {
            public PXPreviousCst(PXGraph graph, string name)
                : base(graph, name)
            {
            }
            public PXPreviousCst(PXGraph graph, Delegate handler)
                : base(graph, handler)
            {
            }

            private PXAdapter origAdapter;

            [PXUIField(DisplayName = ActionsMessages.Previous, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
            [PXPreviousButton]
            protected override IEnumerable Handler(PXAdapter adapter)
            {
                origAdapter = adapter;
                adapter = PrepareCustomNavAdapter(this, adapter, true);
                return base.Handler(adapter);
            }

            protected override IEnumerable InsertAndGet(PXAdapter adapter)
            {
                if (!_inserted)
                {
                    return base.InsertAndGet(origAdapter);
                }
                else
                {
                    return base.InsertAndGet(adapter);
                }
            }
        }

        public class PXNextCst<TNode> : PXNext<TNode>
            where TNode : class, IBqlTable, new()
        {
            public PXNextCst(PXGraph graph, string name)
                : base(graph, name)
            {
            }
            public PXNextCst(PXGraph graph, Delegate handler)
                : base(graph, handler)
            {
            }

            private PXAdapter origAdapter;

            [PXUIField(DisplayName = ActionsMessages.Next, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
            [PXNextButton]
            protected override IEnumerable Handler(PXAdapter adapter)
            {
                origAdapter = adapter;
                adapter = PrepareCustomNavAdapter(this, adapter, true);

                var primaryCache = Graph.Views[Graph.PrimaryView].Cache;
                object current = primaryCache.Current;
                if (current != null && primaryCache.GetStatus(current) == PXEntryStatus.Inserted)
                {
                    adapter.StartRow--;
                }
                return base.Handler(adapter);
            }

            protected override IEnumerable InsertAndGet(PXAdapter adapter)
            {
                if (!_inserted)
                {
                    return base.InsertAndGet(origAdapter);
                }
                else
                {
                    return base.InsertAndGet(adapter);
                }
            }
        }

        public class PXLastCst<TNode> : PXLast<TNode>
            where TNode : class, IBqlTable, new()
        {
            public PXLastCst(PXGraph graph, string name)
                : base(graph, name)
            {
            }
            public PXLastCst(PXGraph graph, Delegate handler)
                : base(graph, handler)
            {
            }
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = ActionsMessages.Last, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
            [PXLastButton]
            protected override IEnumerable Handler(PXAdapter adapter)
            {
                adapter = PrepareCustomNavAdapter(this, adapter);
                return base.Handler(adapter);
            }
        }

        public static PXAdapter PrepareCustomNavAdapter(PXAction action, 
            PXAdapter adapter, bool prevNextAction = false)
        {
            var select = adapter.View.BqlSelect;
            select = select.OrderByNew<OrderBy<
                Desc<FSAppointment.createdDateTime,
                Desc<FSAppointment.srvOrdType,
                Desc<FSAppointment.refNbr>>>>>();

            var newAdapter = new PXAdapter(new PXView(action.Graph, true, select))
            {
                MaximumRows = adapter.MaximumRows
            };

            object current = action.Graph.Views[action.Graph.PrimaryView].Cache.Current;
            if (prevNextAction)
            {
                var sortColumns = new string[adapter.SortColumns.Count() + 1];
                adapter.SortColumns.CopyTo(sortColumns, 1);
                sortColumns[0] = "CreatedDateTime";
                newAdapter.SortColumns = sortColumns;

                var descendings = new bool[adapter.Descendings.Count() + 1];
                adapter.Descendings.CopyTo(descendings, 1);
                descendings[0] = true;
                newAdapter.Descendings = descendings;

                var searches = new object[adapter.Searches.Count() + 1];
                adapter.Searches.CopyTo(searches, 1);
                if (current != null && current is FSAppointment)
                    searches[0] = ((FSAppointment)current).CreatedDateTime;
                newAdapter.Searches = searches;
            }
            else if (current != null)
            {
                adapter.Currents = new object[] { current };
            }

            return newAdapter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help in this but still replacement of Appointments page with Generic Page won't do. And, even if these code would work for the navigation functionalities, I am more worried about other actions. For an example, Delete action isn't working either. And what about those other actions, I don't think it would be wise to go and replace all the code all over the places. 
http://www.screencast.com/t/yBPRs1W93

Sorry, if I am being too naive.

Comment: @BikashLama, you don't need to override/customize other actions. Could you please create a brand new Acumatica instance on your machine and apply only the code snippet from above? If you need further assistance, this has to move to a support case with Acumatica...